# iteration over fk in django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

if I have table like this represented in django model

```
person
------
id
name

worker
------
personid
jobid

job
---
id
desc
wage

w=Worker.objects.filter(<some sort of filter)
```

now I want all `persons` that are related in `w`
`w` is given I can not use that statement.

eventually I want to return a json string that represents a `dict`
with `idperson` as key and `{"job":jobid,"wage":wage}` as
one value in list of `jobs` for that key

Comment: "I want all persons that are related "?  Related to what?

Comment: `w` contains list of `workers` I want a list of `persons` from that `w`

Comment: If you have the list of workers, you have the list of persons, based on the foreign key.

Comment: @CraigKerstiens, I know, I want unique list of persons that listed in `w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

```
Person.objects.filter(worker__id__in=[worker.pk for worker in w])
```

credit to support

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to us an in, with any collection of objects you wish. It should look something like:

```
w = Worker.objects.filter(job__in=Job.objects.filter(somefilterhere))
```

From here of course you could iterate over your workers and build up your list:

```
somelist = []
for worker in w:
    somelist.append({'person': worker.person.id, 'wage': worker.job.wage})
```

Comment: person can have many jobs, and I'll receive  duplicates that way